# "Standard representation" and their irreducibility

Tags: representation-theory

I think the standard representation of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is irreducible, simply because for every $g\in GL_n(\mathbb{C}))$ there is a $\alpha\neq 0$ scalar with $\alpha g$ in $SL_n$. Is this a correct proof? What are more general conditions on a subgroup $G$ of $GL_n$ that assure that the standard representation is irreducible? Thanks!

Comment: You still want to say that $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Yes @JendrikStelzner. Actually does this also work out over other fields? say over the reals. I think i am using crucially the property that it is algebraically closed?

Comment: It should work for $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ over ever field $K$: For $n = 1$ this is clear. If $n \geq 2$ then there exists for every $x \in K^n \setminus \{0\}$ some $S \in \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ with $S e_1 = x$ (i.e. we can extend $x$ to a basis of $K^n$). We can rescale to second column of $S$ by the factor $1/(\det S)$ to get $S' \in \mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ with $S'e_1 = x$. So the Orbit of $e_1$ under the natural action of $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ ist $K^n \setminus \{0\}$. So $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ acts transitively on $K^n \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner ah you arrgue in that way. I just took the $n$-th root of the determinant